# python Client hangs when no data to receive from server and hangs in that thread w/o letting client send

Tags: python, multithreading, client, locking

I am trying to figure out how to get my client to send and receive data 'simultaneously' and am using threads.  My problem is that, depending on the way I set it up, the way here it waits for data from the server in the recieveFromServer function which is in its own thread and cannot stop it when nothing will be sent.  The other way it just waits for user input, and will send to the server and then I'd call the function recieveFromServer after the client sends a message to the server which doesn't allow for fluent communication, but cannot get it to alternate automatically.  How do I release the thread when the client has nothing to be sent, or there is no more to be received from the server.

It would get to long if I tried to explain everything I have tried. :)

Thanks.

The client:

```
from socket import *
from threading import *
import thread
import time
from struct import pack,unpack
from networklingo import *
#from exception import *

HOST = '192.168.0.105'
PORT = 21567
BUFFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)

lock = thread.allocate_lock()

class TronClient:

    def __init__(self,control=None):
        self.tcpSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        #self.tcpSock.settimeout(.2)
        self.recvBuff = []

    def connect(self):
        self.tcpSock.connect(ADDR)
        self.clientUID = self.tcpSock.recv(BUFFSIZE)
        print 'My clientUID is ', self.clientUID
        t = Thread(target = self.receiveFromSrv())
        t.setDaemon(1)
        t.start()
        print 'going to main loop'
        self.mainLoop()
        #t = Thread(target = self.mainLoop())
        #t.setName('mainLoop')
        #t.setDaemon(1)
        #t.start()

    def receiveFromSrv(self):
        RECIEVING = 1
        while RECIEVING:
            #print 'Attempting to retrieve more data'
            #lock.acquire()
            #print 'Lock Aquired in recieveFromSrv'

            #try:
            data = self.tcpSock.recv(BUFFSIZE)
            #except socket.timeout,e:
                    #print 'Error recieving data, ',e
                    #continue
            #print data
            if not data: continue

            header = data[:6]
            msgType,msgLength,clientID = unpack("hhh",header)
            print msgType
            print msgLength
            print clientID,'\n'

            msg = data[6:]

            while len(msg) < msgLength:
                data = self.tcpSock.recv(BUFFSIZE)
                dataLen = len(data)

                if dataLen <= msgLength:
                    msg += data
                else:
                    remLen = msgLength-len(data) #we just need to retrieve first bit of data to complete msg 
                    msg += data[:remLen]
                    self.recvBuff.append(data[remLen:])

            print msg
            #else:
                #lock.release()
            #    print 'lock release in receiveFromSrv'
                #time.sleep(2)
            #RECIEVING = 0

    def disconnect(self,data=''):
        self.send(DISCONNECT_REQUEST,data)
        #self.tcpSock.close()

    def send(self,msgType,msg):
        header = pack("hhh",msgType,len(msg),self.clientUID)
        msg = header+msg
        self.tcpSock.send(msg)

    def mainLoop(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                #lock.acquire()
                #print 'lock aquired in mainLoop'
                data = raw_input('> ')
            except EOFError:            # enter key hit without any data (blank line) so ignore and continue
                continue                

            #if not data or data == '':  # no valid data so just continue
            #    continue

            if data=='exit':            # client wants to disconnect, so send request to server
                self.disconnect()
                break
            else:
                self.send(TRON_CHAT,data)

            #lock.release()
            #print 'lock released in main loop'
            #self.recieveFromSrv()
            #data = self.tcpSock.recv(BUFFSIZE)
            #t = Thread(target = self.receiveFromSrv())
            #t.setDaemon(1)
            #t.start()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli = TronClient()
    cli.connect()
    #t = Thread(target = cli.connect())
    #t.setName('connect')
    #t.setDaemon(1)
    #t.start()
```

The server (uses a lock when incrementing or decrementing number of clients):

```
from socket import *
from threading import *
import thread
from controller import *
from networklingo import *
from struct import pack,unpack

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)

nclntlock = thread.allocate_lock()

class TronServer:

    def __init__(self,maxConnect=4,control=None):
        self.servSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

        # ensure that you can restart server quickly when it terminates
        self.servSock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,1)

        self.servSock.bind(ADDR)
        self.servSock.listen(maxConnect)

        # keep track of number of connected clients
        self.clientsConnected = 0

        # give each client a unique identfier for this run of server
        self.clientUID = 0

        # list of all clients to cycle through for sending
        self.allClients = {}

        # keep track of threads
        self.cliThreads = {}

        #reference back to controller
        self.controller = control

        self.recvBuff = []

    def removeClient(self,clientID,addr):
        if clientID in self.allClients.keys():
            self.allClients[clientID].close()
            print "Disconnected from", addr
            nclntlock.acquire()
            self.clientsConnected -= 1
            nclntlock.release()
            del self.allClients[clientID]
        else:
            print 'ClientID is not valid'

    def recieve(self,clientsock,addr):
        RECIEVING = 1

        # loop serving the new client
        while RECIEVING: # while PLAYING???
            try:
                data = clientsock.recv(BUFSIZE)
            except:
                RECIEVING = 0
                continue

#            if not data: break  #no data was recieved

            if data != '':
                print 'Recieved msg from client: ',data

                header = data[:6]
                msgType,msgLength,clientID = unpack("hhh",header)
                print msgType
                print msgLength
                print clientID,'\n'

                if msgType == DISCONNECT_REQUEST:               #handle disconnect request
                    self.removeClient(clientID,addr)
                else:                                           #pass message type and message off to controller

                    msg = data[6:]

                    while len(msg) < msgLength:
                        data = self.tcpSock.recv(BUFSIZE)
                        dataLen = len(data)

                        if dataLen <= msgLength:
                            msg += data
                        else:
                            remLen = msgLength-len(data) #we just need to retrieve first bit of data to complete msg 
                            msg += data[:remLen]
                            self.recvBuff.append(data[remLen:])

                    print msg       
            # echo back the same data you just recieved
            #clientsock.sendall(data)
                    self.send(TRON_CHAT,msg,-1) #send to client 0


        for k in self.allClients.keys():
            if self.allClients[k] == clientsock:
                self.removeClient(k,addr)
                print 'deleted after hard exit from clientID ', k
                #self.cliThreads[k].join()
                #del self.cliThreads[k]
                # then tell controller to delete player with k
                break

    def send(self,msgType,msg,clientID=-1):
        header = pack("hhh",msgType,len(msg),clientID)
        msg = header+msg

        if clientID in self.allClients:
            self.allClients[clientID].send(msg)
        elif clientID==ALL_PLAYERS:
            for k in self.allClients.keys():
                self.allClients[k].send(msg)


    def mainLoop(self):
        global nclntlock

        try:
            while self.controller != None and self.controller.state == WAITING:
                print 'awaiting connections'
                clientsock, caddy = self.servSock.accept()

                nclntlock.acquire()                         
                self.clientsConnected += 1
                nclntlock.release()
                print 'Client ',self.clientUID,' connected from:',caddy
                clientsock.setblocking(0)
                clientsock.send(str(self.clientUID))
                self.allClients[self.clientUID] = clientsock
                t = Thread(target = self.recieve, args = [clientsock,caddy])
                t.setName('recieve-' + str(self.clientUID))
                self.cliThreads[self.clientUID] = t
                self.clientUID += 1
                # t.setDaemon(1)
                t.start()
        finally:
            self.servSock.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serv = TronServer(control = LocalController(nPlayers = 3, fWidth = 70, fHeight = 10))
    t = Thread(target = serv.mainLoop())
    t.setName('mainLoop')
#   t.setDaemon(1)
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to try and set the socket to non-blocking mode:

http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking

> Set blocking or non-blocking mode of
>   the socket: if flag is 0, the socket
>   is set to non-blocking, else to
>   blocking mode. Initially all sockets
>   are in blocking mode. In non-blocking
>   mode, if a recv() call doesn’t find
>   any data, or if a send() call can’t
>   immediately dispose of the data, a
>   error exception is raised; in blocking
>   mode, the calls block until they can
>   proceed. s.setblocking(0) is
>   equivalent to s.settimeout(0);
>   s.setblocking(1) is equivalent to
>   s.settimeout(None).

Also, instead of using raw sockets, have you considdered using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module. It is a higher-level abstraction for doing network IO. The section on [Pipes & Queues](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) is specific to sending and receiving data between a client/server.

Comment: Thank-you for the response.  I have tried self.tcpSock.setblocking(0) before the recv call, however seems to make no difference and kept it in the server code anyways (for now).

I've been taking a look at the multiprocessing module and do you happen to know if it would be easy to integrate that with what I already have as I am just learning python?  I'm not exactly sure how I would use one of these approaches.

Thanks in advance for the help.